# How put value in each xml node

Tags: c#, xml

I have generated xmldocument by this code with C#,

```
  protected XDocument generateXML()
    {
        XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
 new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
     new XElement("Invoices",
         new XElement("Invoice",
             new XElement("InvoiceNumber", "s10838652")
         .......

 return xdoc;
```

}

and in another method I have:

```
    public override void RunWintrackConnector()
    {

        XDocument xml = generateXML();
```

.....

Then I would like to put data in each XML node: (instead of s10838652 I would like to assign (string.Concat(bill.invoice, bill.num);) to the InvoiceNumber node.)

I have the right part but not sure how get access to each node of xml:

```
xmlnode(for example InvoiceNumber) =  Win2.IntegrationXML.XMLMisc.DirtyData.getStringValue(string.Concat(bill.invoice, bill.num));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xml
    .Elements("Invoices")
    .Elements("Invoice")
    .Elements("InvoiceNumber")
    .First()
    .Value = string.Concat(bill.invoice, bill.num);
```

edit - to go over all your invoices:

```
foreach(var invoice in xml.Elements("Invoices").Elements("Invoice"))
{
    invoice.Element("InvoiceNumber").Value = "asdf";
}
```

If you are familiar with XPath, this is equivalent to selecting all invoices with "Invoices/Invoice".

Comment: should I have   xml
                    .Elements("Invoices")
                    .Elements("Invoice")    for all of the nodes? because its is like 50 nodes so I should repeat this in all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XElement` or `XDocument` to write the values you need.

```
var valueToInsert = Win2.IntegrationXML.XMLMisc.DirtyData
    .getStringValue(string.Concat(bill.invoice, bill.num));

XDocument xml = generateXML();
xml.Element("Invoices")
    .Elements("Invoice").First() //this First is just an example
    .Element("InvoiceNumber")
    .Value = valueToInsert;
```

[`Element()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) Returns the first found child node, and [`Elements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.elements.aspx) gets a list of all child nodes with that node name. Find out your pattern of how nodes are nested and you should be all set.

As a side note, you can do the above with a `XDocument` variable, but I prefer to keep everything as `XElement` for the added Linq compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, but do I need to repeat ml.Element("Invoices")
    .Elements("Invoice").First() for all the nodes?

Comment: @nik, use a combination of `Element` and `Elements` to get the required values. Use the links I provided to learn about what they do. What I wrote was only a sample. It is up to you to figure out the right pattern for your code.